# <!--more--> help

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, template-tags, read-more

I have a custom post type called "Blog", in my templates I looping over the blog type and doing the following,

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <section class="news">
                <h2 class="title"><?php echo strtolower(the_title()); ?></h2>
                <h4><?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail();?> Posted By <?php the_author(); ?> - <?php the_date("l jS M Y"); ?></h4>
                <p class="tags">
                    <?php $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID); ?>
                    <?php foreach ($tags as $tag) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>"> <?php echo $tag->name; ?> </a> |
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </p>
                    <?php the_content("Read More"); ?>
            </section>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

My post consists of this content,

```
Hello World I am teaser  
<!--more-->  
Hello World I am a the content
```

I am expecting the output to looks like this,

```
Hello Word I am teaser
<a href="link_url">Read More</a>
```

However what I am getting is the following,

```
   Hello World I am teaser  

   Hello World I am a the content
```

Comment: I would look in your theme's function file to see if it is being stripped out for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the global `$more` variable before you call `the_content()`. e.g.:

```
<?php
global $more;
$more = 0;
the_content( 'Read More' );
?>
```

(This is how you [enable the "Read More" tag for Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#How_to_use_Read_More_in_Pages).)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing what you have wit this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <section class="news">
        <h2 class="title"><?php echo strtolower(the_title()); ?></h2>
        <h4><?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail();?> Posted By <?php the_author(); ?> - <?php the_date("l jS M Y"); ?></h4>
        <p class="tags">
            <?php $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID); ?>
            <?php foreach ($tags as $tag) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>"> <?php echo $tag->name; ?> </a> |
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </p>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </section>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Then add this to your functions.php in place of what is now there for the more tag (if any exists):

```
<?php
function all_excerpts_get_more_link($post_excerpt) {
  return '' . $post_excerpt . '' . '<span class="readmore"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read More' . '</span>';
}
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'all_excerpts_get_more_link');
?>
```